# How to overlay gradient mesh on top of text cutting the gradient out of negative space

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask, gradient-mesh

I have some arched vector text. I created a mesh gradient but I can not figure out how to overlay it just within the letters.  Being a mesh I can't seem to make a compound path or clipping mask.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the **type** you need to use as a clipping mask. Specifically a *duplicate* of the type. You don't need a clipping mask using the mesh object. You *want* a clipping mask *applied* to the mesh object.

- Copy the type (I'm assuming it's outlines and not live type)
- Paste in front of the mesh
- Then select the type copy and the gradient mesh
- Choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make` from the menu

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Following your directions tho I get an error message "Can't make clipping mask. a path used as a clipping mask must contain at least 2 connected anchor points."

Comment: I just tried it again --got a different error message:  "The top object is very complex and may cause the document to fail print or preview of used as a mask. Do you want to make a mask anyway?"  And on yes it completely disappears as in everything goes transparent

Comment: Here's a link to the file if it helps:  
http://www.pixelmixing.com/SM-header-type-gradient-mesh.ai

Comment: Separating the letters one by one I got it to work by (weirdly) making a group of one letter and then following your directions.  But that means a LOT of work. :\

Comment: @Marc We typically do **not** do direct file adjustments for users here. They are typically of little use to *any* other visitor. However, check the updated answer. The issue you are facing is because the type object is a group of shapes, it's not a single object (Compound path). Essentially the problem you face is due to how the type is constructed - which is *very* specific to your file. If this is "a lot of work" then I'm afraid you may be expecting too much from software.

Comment: Apology if I was not clear. I just meant if I had to make each and every gradient mesh, for each and every letter, one by one process  --that'd be a lot of work. Thank you Scott.

Comment: If this solved your problem @Marc please mark the answer correct.